# Скачивание файлов с сервера AJAX-ом

Tags: ajax, файлы, servlet

Подскажите пожалуйста как скачать файл с сервера при помощи `ajax`? При чём мне нужно указать не полный путь, а допустим путь к файлу от корня сайта, к примеру - `\tmp\test.txt`. Серверная часть написана на `Java`, тобишь запрос должен приходить на сервлету.

Может есть готовые решения которые работаю так

Решение [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax/9970672#9970672)

Comment: вы хотите сохранить файл на диск у клиента?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да.

Comment: Надеюсь это невозможно) Хотя, вас же устроит стандартный диалог сохранения файла?

Comment: @vp_arth да. устроит

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны создать ссылку на странице, которая должна указывать на файл. После клика по этой ссылке браузер скачает файл. Файл может создаваться динамически в servlet.

Через AJAX это сделать нельзя по соображениям безопасности.

Comment: можно пример? пожалуйста

Comment: пример чего именно?

Comment: такого скачивания. мне нужно что бы я не переходил на другую вкладку, а оставался в этой же и при этом скачивал файл

Comment: переход на другую вкладку зависит от настроек браузера в больше степени, чем от ссылки.

Comment: уже решил проблему

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: А разве `HTML5` не обходит ограничение отправки данных `AJAX`'ом через `FormData` ?

Comment: @faoxis а как связана отправка данных и получение файла?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно инициировать стандартную процедуру скачивания - переход по прямой ссылке:

```
function download(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
  // window.open(url);
};
```

Можно попробовать сделать это в скрытом `iframe`, но пользователь должен выбрать расположение файла сам, стандартными средствами.

---

Если файл генерируется динамически, сервлет должен отдавать корректные заголовки.
Например:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="My file.bin"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 24017
```

Comment: не скачивает - просто переходит по ссылке и всё. Я попробовал скачать `html` файл - открыл, картинку - тоже самое.

Comment: Не динамически. файл уже есть на сервере.